# Не происходит сброс таймера при вызове clearTimeout

Tags: javascript

Проблема такая, не происходит сброс таймера при повторном вызове функции `msg()`.

```
function msg(a,b) {
    $("div").remove(".message");
    $("body").append('<div class="message"><div class="message_head '+a+'"></div><span>'+b+'</span><div class="close"></div></div>');
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    var timerId = setTimeout(function() {$("div").remove(".message");},5000);
}
```

Comment: ето потому что `clearTimeout` не в курсе что такое `timerId` определите ету переменную вне функции `msg` и попробюуйте

Comment: Чуть поясню предыдущих ораторов: каждый вызов функции приводит к созданию нового объекта переменных, т. е. каждый раз `timerId` создаётся как в первый раз. И ID таймера, который был присвоен ей в прошлом, канет в небытие из-за уничтожения переменных при выходе из функции. Что делать - уже описали ранее.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переменная `timerId` должна быть видна другим вызовам функции `msg`. Проще всего будет определить переменную на предыдущем уровне вложенности.

```
var timerId = 0;

function msg(a,b) {
  // тут ваш код
  clearTimeout(timerId);
  timerId = setTimeout(function() {
      // ваш код
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь.